# NestJS - debug with watch mode - port already in use

Tags: debugging, nestjs, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a problem with the debug in my NestJS app.

My setup:

- Windows + WSL2
- PhpStorm
- Docker
- Node 18.18
- NestJS 10.3.0

package.json

```
"start:debug": "nest start --debug=0.0.0.0:9229 --watch"
```

PhpStorm Run/Debug config

[image]

- I run the command `npm run start:debug`, my app spins up properly
- I start the debug (<kbd>Shift + F9</kbd>) in PhpStorm, it connects to my app, I see "Debugger attached." in the terminal. It takes a while (like 30s) though.
- I make some changes in my code, and my app rebuilds automatically (because of the `--watch`)
- I see `Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use` in the terminal, the debugger is not able to connect again.

The only way to make it work again is to <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to stop the whole process and run it again.

Is there a way to set up it this way so that I wouldn't need to restart the app after I change anything? I don't see anything in the NestJS docs that `--watch` and `--debug` can't work together.

Comment: See if a comment here will be of any help: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62138

Comment: @LazyOne I've tried both without specifying any port (then it uses 9229 anyway) and setting other ports like 6666. Every time the result is the same - it works until I make some change in my code

Comment: Try commenting in the ticket (by answering those questions -- providing detailed info on how you are doing it -- screen recording is the best way) -- JetBrains support usually can help with such issues -- tell what is wrong / offer workarounds .. or make an actual bug ticket (especially if you can provide a simple test project + steps to reproduce)

Comment: Dang.. I've just realised that you have mentioned Docker and WSL2. Please check the following ticket as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50014 (not exactly your setup (not using `--watch` as far as I can see) but worth checking anyway).

Comment: @LazyOne and it looks like it's a different problem. He is not able to connect at all. 

Also, it looks like some Node / Nest issue rather than PhpStorm. It isn't able to restart the debug process itself, as I mentioned: I'm getting `Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use` in the console. Even if we skip connecting with PhpStorm completely.

Comment: I mentioned that I am able to connect, just to show that it works before changing something